# Customize element of a paid template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress managed page with a paid template. I need to modify a pop-up of this template that has manageable options that currently do not exist under said template (Activate on specific pages, sizes, among others). If I touch the direct code of the template, I suppose that the most possible thing is that when I update or for some reason reinstall the template, I lose what has been developed or I have to take a backup every time I do it, which would not be efficient. Is there any way to make this manageable or what other solutions do you recommend? Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with [child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)? If not then have a look at the documentation, a child theme sounds like what you need here. Alternatively you could just build a small, custom plugin that adds this functionality to the site without needing to modify the original template.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of case, you can use the child theme of the main theme. If there is no child theme you can generate it from here https://childtheme-generator.com/.

The Child theme mainly inherits all of the features of main theme. If you make any changes in the child theme then it won't be lost even if you update the main theme.

For more information about child theme please follow this article https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Thank you